# C language. Read from stdout

Tags: c, stdout

I have some troubles with a library function.
I have to write some C code that uses a library function which prints on the screen its internal steps. 
I am not interested to its return value, but only to printed steps.
So, I think I have to read from standard output and to copy read strings in a buffer.
I already tried fscanf and dup2 but I can't read from standard output. Please, could anyone help me?

Comment: Show the code you tried, please!  If you made a pipe and used `dup2` correctly you should have been able to do what you're trying.

Answer (score 17):

An expanded version of the previous answer, without using files, and capturing stdout in a pipe, instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
   int  stdout_bk; //is fd for stdout backup

   printf("this is before redirection\n");
   stdout_bk = dup(fileno(stdout));

   int pipefd[2];
   pipe2(pipefd, 0); // O_NONBLOCK);

   // What used to be stdout will now go to the pipe.
   dup2(pipefd[1], fileno(stdout));

   printf("this is printed much later!\n");
   fflush(stdout);//flushall();
   write(pipefd[1], "good-bye", 9); // null-terminated string!
   close(pipefd[1]);

   dup2(stdout_bk, fileno(stdout));//restore
   printf("this is now\n");

   char buf[101];
   read(pipefd[0], buf, 100); 
   printf("got this from the pipe >>>%s<<<\n", buf);
}
```

Generates the following output:

```
this is before redirection
this is now
got this from the pipe >>>this is printed much later!
good-bye<<<
```

Comment: What an awesome answer!

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to open a pipe, dup the write end into stdout and then read from the read-end of the pipe, something like the following, with error checking:

```
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
dup2(fds[1], stdout);
read(fds[0], buf, buf_sz);
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed it with a non pure solution. I used C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
    FILE *fp;
    int  stdout_bk;//is fd for stdout backup

    stdout_bk = dup(fileno(stdout));
    fp=fopen("temp.txt","w");//file out, after read from file
    dup2(fileno(fp), fileno(stdout));
    /* ... */
    fflush(stdout);//flushall();
    fclose(fp);

    dup2(stdout_bk, fileno(stdout));//restore
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant the standard input. Another possible function is `gets`, use `man gets` to understand how it works (pretty simple). Please show your code and explain where you failed for a better answer.

Comment: No, OP is talking about `stdout`.  He has a library function that writes to `stdout`, and he wants to intercept that output.

Comment: ok, but there is still a thing I don't undestand.
Why if I want read the written file, i can't?
I cannot post the code 'cause 8 hours have to pass :S