# Writing a struct into a file but reading it incorrectly

Tags: c, struct, io, fwrite, fread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student
{
    int id;
    int grade;
};

struct Student john;

int main()
{

    john.id = 100;
    john.grade = 80;

    struct Student steve;

    fwrite(&john, sizeof(struct Student), 1, stdout);
    fread(&steve, sizeof(struct Student), 1, stdout);

    printf("\n%d %d \n", steve.id, steve.grade);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a `struct` into a file(in this case it is stdout), then I am trying to read it.

The values it prints are random, what could be the reason?

Comment: You do know that `stdout` is the ***output*** file handle of the terminal or console? I suggest you start by adding error checking to all functions that can return a success/failure, like `fwrite` and `fread`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, but does that make a difference ? Aren't they all treated as files ?

Comment: File can be read-only, write-only, or read-write. `stdout` is write-only. This is basically what the second argument to [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) is for.

Comment: What do you mean by "random"?  I would expect the write to successfully write the values, but they won't display nicely on your screen.  The `fread` I would expect to fail.

Comment: Perhaps think about it like this: `stdout` is the *console* or *terminal*. Where would data you write to `stdout` actually be stored? It's just written into the console or terminal.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Okey the first part is always dP which corresponds to 100 and 80.But the other two values are random.

Comment: always check for return types specially when doing IO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you cannot read from `stdout`, however you could do it in a file that can be opened to read and write, you can even *replace* `stdout` with such file, for instance in UNIX uising unnamed pipes, chek [C language. Read from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071702/6865932).

However you'd still need to reposition your file offset after you write so you can read from the beggining of the file, example:

```
int main()
{

    john.id = 100;
    john.grade = 80;

    FILE* f = fopen("test", "w+"); // check return value..

    struct Student steve;

    fwrite(&john, sizeof(struct Student), 1, f); // same here...

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); // <-- reset offset, (or lseek if you're using a file descritor)

    fread(&steve, sizeof(struct Student), 1, f); // and here

    printf("\n%d %d \n", steve.id, steve.grade);

    fclose(f);

}
```