# Reading only requested terminal output

Tags: bash

I have my minecraft `server.jar` application that prints a log to the terminal. While I know you can log output from a specific shell by using the `script` command, that seems a bit heavy for my application. I want to scan each line of the shell and check if it's useful before grabbing it. What c++ functions are able to do this?

Even better, if I could start the program only when I've triggered my `server.jar` file that'd be really efficient.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071702/c-language-read-from-stdout) is potentially relevant information on reading through a pipeline.

Comment: I would imagine you would just want to pipe the output to your program, and then read it from its stdin, i.e. something like `java -jar server.jar |./program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading through a pipeline. I have done some research on the [spigot site](https://www.spigotmc.org/) and have discovered that it uses [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc.html) as its logger. I can grab information via this and push it to a database using hikariCP/JBDC and take from there.